# Existence of a Borel measurable function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $Y\subset X$ be a compact set. Assume that $f_1, f_2: Y \to \mathbb{P}\mathbb{R}^2$ are continuous functions. Let $N \subset \mathbb{P}\mathbb{R}^2$ be a countable set.

#### Question

Is there  a Borel measurable function $T:f_1(Y) \to f_2(Y)$ such that if $x \in Y$ and $f_1(x) \notin N$, then $T(f_1(x))=f_2(x)$?

Comment: This may be my ignorance showing, but what is the motivation for this question? At the moment, it seems quite arbitrary.

Comment: That is a small past of theorem that I am going to prove, but I don't know whether one can find such a function or not.

Comment: What is the role of X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y=[-1,1]$. We can also view $Y$ by homeomorphic embedding and abuse of notation as a subset of $\mathbb{P}\mathbb{R}^2$. For all $x\in Y$, let $f_1(x)=|x|$ and $f_2(x)=x$. For all but the countably many $x$ such that $f_1(x)=|x|\in N$, one would need $$x=f_2(x)=T(f_1(x))=T(|x|)=T(|-x|)=T(f_1(-x))=f_2(-x)=-x,$$
which is impossible.